# Send email on SharePoint checkin

Tags: vba, sharepoint

I was wondering if there is a way to send an email to someone when a file is checked in on SharePoint. I want to be able to send an email when someone checks in the file, with only the record that the person updated in the excel sheet.

Comment: You should share more information on the SharePoint version etc

Comment: So I want to be able to write the query in excel VBA. Reason being I do not have access to the SharePoint designer section, so each time I upload from excel I want to be able to be send out an email, with the last updated row.